# Adding empty lines between sentences in text file

Tags: java, arrays, char, newline

So I have the following sentences in a text file:

```
Something I don't know
Something else as well
And this here
And that
```

And I want to make it look like this

```
Something I don't know

Something else as well

And this here

And that
```

I know the code up to the point that I copy the content in a character array but I don't know how to add the extra '\n' character in between the array.

EDIT: Added the code.

```
import java.io.*;
class File_Tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int S=0;
    char [] src = new char[300];
    FileReader fr;
    try{
    fr = new FileReader("src.txt");
    fr.read(src);
    fr.close();
    }catch (IOException io) 
    {
     System.out.println(io.toString());
     return;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<src.length;i++)
    {
    if (src[i]==' ') 
    {
     src[i]='@';
     S++;
    }
    else if (src[i]=='\n')
    }
    try{
    File file = new File("dest.txt");
    file.createNewFile();
    FileWriter dest = new FileWriter(file);
    dest.write(src,0,src.length);
    dest.close();
    }catch (IOException io) 
    {
     System.out.println(io.toString());
     return;
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: Is it one sentence per line? You don't need Java to do this, this can be done in command line.

Comment: Why do you even need to copy everything to a `char[]`? Why not just work with `String`s/`StringBuilder`s?

Comment: How about posting your code, instead of making us guess what it might look like?

Comment: Added the code. I want to know if I can do it with a for loop rather than stringbuilder (it's an excersise and I don't know if i am allowed to use it)

Comment: Start by reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html, which shows how to **correctly** copy every character from one file to another. Then adapt it to insert additional line separators when needed. Your method is completely incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which version of Java you use so Java 8 is assumed:

```
final Path src = Paths.get("src.txt");
final Path dst = Paths.get("dst.txt");

// Does UTF-8 by default
try (
    final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(src);
    final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(dst);
) {
    lines.forEach(line -> {
        writer.write(line);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.newLine();
    });
}
```

Note that this inserts a further newline at the end of the file.

Comment: I use Java 5 and I try to make it as less complicated as possible